# after_update if statement based on attribute values Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to send a notification based on a project's status but can't quite get the logic right - my code is running `:create_slack_notify_job` after any update, however I want `:create_slack_notify_job` to run only after a specific kind of update (when the project's status was changed to "Active"), not after any attribute update. My `after_update` is below - any ideas on how to make that run as explained?

`after_update :create_slack_notify_job, 
if: Proc.new{|project|project.status_changed? && project.status == 'Active' }`

Comment: I understand what you're wanting to happen, what _is_ happening with your current code?

Comment: Currently, `:create_slack_notify_job` runs after any update that happens. So if the project status is updated to "Inactive" (or any other status), after_update still runs. But I want it to only run when the project status is updated to "Active" and only "Active". Does that make more sense?

Comment: That makes sense. Can you throw a debugging call in the proc to inspect the actual project attributes to see what the the failure is? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Rails 5.1+ you'll want to use the method `saved_changes` and friends. In particular, you probably want `project.saved_change_to_attribute? :status, to: 'Active'`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-saved_change_to_attribute-3F

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19847

Comment: Hmm I'm running 5.0.6 and am getting this error `undefined method saved_change_to_attribute?`

Comment: Whoops, it was introduced in v5.1+ sorry about that.